# Перевод изображения в матрицу чисел

Tags: c++

С помощью каких библиотек можно представить изображение в виде матрицы чисел RGB

Comment: GDI, GDI+ (на Windows).

Comment: OpenCV, AviSynth

Answer (score 1):

Так как Вы не указали, ни платформу, ни типы изображений, то ответ такой

- Qt (хотя это не совсем библиотека) - класс `QImage`, функция `pixel(x,y)`
- ImageMagick/GraphicMagick

Answer (score 0):

wxWidgets позволяет через `wxImage` получить массив RGB *непосредственно*, он их в таком виде хранит. Ну, или через соответствующие функции-члены `wxImage`.

Кстати, wxWidgets кроссплатформенный :)